# Compute field is not updating it self odoo 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

The compute field (balance) in account.report class has store=True parm and it is depended on accounts.accounts.entries.balance, it should change when the balance of depended field changed, it's working if add journal.entries record manually but if it's created through exmaple createjournal() function the balance in the account.type and account.report is not updating. any solution to triger the get_balance function.

```
@api.multi
def createjournal(self):
    journal = self.env['journal.entries']
    journal.sudo().create({'name': "new record"})

class JournalEntries(models.Model):
    _name = 'journal.entries'

    debit = fields.Float()
    credit = fields.Float()
    balance = fields.Float(compute="get_balance", store=True)


    @api.depends('credit','debit')
    def get_balance(self):
        for x in self:
            balance = x.debit - x.credit
            x.balance = abs(balance)

class ErpAccount(models.Model):
    _name = 'erp.account'

    entries = fields.One2many('journal.entries','account')
    balance = fields.Float(compute="get_balance")
    debit = fields.Float(compute="get_debit")
    credit = fields.Float(compute="get_credit")

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('debit','credit')
    def get_balance(self):
        for x in self:
            balance = x.debit - x.credit
            x.balance = abs(balance)


    @api.multi
    def get_debit(self):
        for x in self:
            x.debit = sum(line.debit for line in x.entries)


    @api.multi
    def get_credit(self):
        for x in self:
            x.credit = sum(line.credit for line in x.entries)

class AccountType(models.Model):
    _name = 'account.type'

    accounts = fields.One2many('erp.account','account_type')
    balance = fields.Float(compute="get_balance")
    debit = fields.Float(compute="get_debit")
    credit = fields.Float(compute="get_credit")


    @api.multi
    @api.depends('accounts.entries.balance')
    def get_balance(self):
        for x in self:
            x.balance = sum(line.balance for line in x.accounts)


    @api.multi
    def get_debit(self):
        for x in self:
            x.debit = sum(line.debit for line in x.accounts)


    @api.multi
    def get_credit(self):
        for x in self:
            x.credit = sum(line.credit for line in x.accounts)


class AccountReportName(models.Model):
    _name = 'account.report'


    types = fields.One2many('account.type','report_account')
    balance = fields.Float(compute="get_balance", store=True)
    debit = fields.Float(compute="get_debit")
    credit = fields.Float(compute="get_credit")

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('types.accounts.entries.balance')
    def get_balance(self):
        for x in self:
            x.balance = sum(line.balance for line in x.types)


    @api.multi
    def get_debit(self):
        for x in self:
            x.debit = sum(line.debit for line in x.types)


    @api.multi
    def get_credit(self):
        for x in self:
            x.credit = sum(line.credit for line in x.types)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want balance to be updated you should remove  `store=True`
Since this will only be updated when you edit the `journal.entries` record.

Comment: Yes but store is required otherwise it will not appear on search as well on graph

Comment: You could create a custom search function

Comment: And what about value of balance not appearing in graph view

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved i add @api.depends('entries.balance','entries.active') on erp.account and it works fine.